# mysql trace optimizer query_cost anomaly

Tags: mysql

here is my test data:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_query` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uk_age` (`age`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

insert into test_query values
(1, 1, '1'),
(2, 2, '2'),
(3, 3, '3'),
(4, 4, '4'),
(5, 5, '5'),
(6, 6, '6');
```

Execute `explain select * from test_query where age in (2, 3);`

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_query | NULL       | ALL  | uk_age        | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    6 |    33.33 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

execute `select * from test_query where age in (2, 3);`

```
+----+-----+------+
| id | age | name |
+----+-----+------+
|  2 |   2 | 2    |
|  3 |   3 | 3    |
+----+-----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

execute `show status like "last_query_cost";`

```
+-----------------+----------+
| Variable_name   | Value    |
+-----------------+----------+
| Last_query_cost | 2.199000 |
+-----------------+----------+
```

but use trace optimizer get , table scan cost 4.3, use age index scan cost 4.41, the last result cost 2.199, i don't know how the 2.199 caculate

my expected last_query_cost is 4.3